# SQL/PLSQL - automate the following through batch

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file, plsql

Please help me to do the following,

1. First I need to connect to sql plus with username/Passwd@SID to check for the value.
   For this I have variable to the query like below,

   ```
   declare @Extract uniqueidentifier
   select @Extract = select extract from integration where number='1000';
   ```
2. Based on the value (say 0), it has to come out of the loop to trigger the batch.
3. If the value (say 1), batch should not be triggered and mail should be sent might be through batch .

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Here an example if I think I know what you are asking for

```
Declare @Extract int
Declare @Count int
set @Count  = 1

while @Count < 12 --(select MAX(number) + 1 from tablename)
Begin
set @Extract = @count--(select extract from tablename where number = @count)

if @Extract = 0
Begin
--Trigger batch Code
select @count
End

set @count = @count + 1
End
```

Be sure to uncomment the select statement to do an efficient loop of the table

Comment: Thanks for your time. But I need more clarity on this. While checking for the value, there are possibilities for only 0 and 1. I think we need not set @count If I am clear. First I am planning to set a variable to the query. From the result, checking for the value if it is 0, it has to run the script. if it is 1, then it has to be exited mentioning "no need to run".